# Change nullability of list elements without copying list

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I'm calling a third-party function (which I can't change) which returns a list of nullable elements (`List<Int?>`), but I know for certain that all elements are non-null. I then want to pass this list to another third-party function, which takes a list of non-null elements (`List<Int>`). If I cast it, as I do in the code below, I get a warning. If I use `filterNotNull` it copies the list unnecessarily. How can I avoid copying the list and also not triggering an unchecked cast warning?

```
fun foo() {
    val a = bar(includeNullElements = false)
    baz(a.map { it!! })     // Undesirable to copy large list
    baz(a.filterNotNull())  // Undesirable to copy large list
    baz(a as List<Int>)     // Gives unchecked cast warning
}

/**
 * This function comes from a library that I can't change.
 * Returns a very large list of elements known to be non-null,
 * but unfortunately are typed as nullable.
 */
fun bar(includeNullElements: Boolean): List<Int?> = TODO()

/**
 * This function comes from a library that I can't change.
 * Takes a list of non-null elements.
 */
fun baz(a: List<Int>) {
    println(a)
}
```

Comment: You're gonna get the warning with a cast, because you're sidestepping the type safety system and saying *"hey, this isn't actually a `List<Int?>`, it's specifically a `List<Int>`"* which the compiler has no way of verifying. You can hide the warning with `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")` if you want - but what you're doing is inherently unsafe, as far as the compiler is concerned, so the issue is always there. The only way to actually avoid it is with things like `filterNotNull` which allow the compiler to actually guarantee all the items are non-null or a given type, which is obviously slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do if you absolutely don't want to copy the list, is that you cast the list to a non-nullable list, you suppress the warning for an unchecked cast, but you don't do that in an unsafe way, because you check the list before casting:

```
fun <T: Any> List<T?>.asNonNullable(): List<T> {
    if(any { it == null }) throw IllegalArgumentException("unexpected null element")
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return this as List<T>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the *unchecked cast warning* you can use [`filterIsInstance`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-is-instance.html)

```
baz(a.filterIsInstance<Int>())
```

Also you can use [`toList()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-list.html) that performs a *shallow copy* of the list, which is more efficient than using `map` or `filterNotNull` in this scenario.

See this article of [shallow vs deep copy](https://blog.protein.tech/kotlin-shallow-vs-deep-copy-explained-907a72ccbf7a) for more information about copy.

Comment: Thanks for the useful tips, but `filterIsInstance` [also creates a copy](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/924c28507067cbfbf78a6509ea89eabe496e34ca/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L799), as does `toList()`. They are indeed shallow copies, but so are `map` and `filterNotNull`.